# Overriding format and setting its mode for a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As part of a task I have to do I have to somehow override the format call for a class.

This code is meant to work:

```
obj=class()
obj.format('mode_name').format('arg1','arg2')
```

This then returns the result of the custom format for the args using set mode. For example the mode order returns the given strings in opposite order and connects them with a ",".
It feels like I am missing something really basic but I was unable to find anything that allows this functionality.

Comment: You probably don't want to name your class `class`... could you give some examples of exactly what the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: The obj and class were just examples but you are right I should have chosen different ones. The output is a formatted string depending on the mode. For example mode order swaps the order of given strings and concats them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your object's `format` method to return something that itself has a `format` method, you probably want to create another class.

```
class Formatter:
    def __init__(self, mode: str) -> None:
        self._mode = mode

    def format(self, *args: str) -> str:
        if self._mode == 'spaces':
            return ' '.join(args)
        elif self._mode == 'commas':
            return ', '.join(args)
        raise ValueError(f"invalid formatting mode {self._mode}")


class Foo:
    def format(self, mode: str) -> Formatter:
        return Formatter(mode)


foo = Foo()
print(foo.format("commas").format('arg1', 'arg2'))
# arg1, arg2
```

It might be easier if the first `format` returned a single **function** you could call directly rather than an **object** with a single method; that would allow you to simply define the function inline, which might be preferable if the formatting logic is relatively simple.  (It's also kinda confusing IMO to have code with two `format` methods that do completely different things!)  Here's how that might look:

```
class Foo:
    def format(self, mode: str) -> callable:
        def formatter(*args: str) -> str:
            if mode == 'spaces':
                return ' '.join(args)
            elif mode == 'commas':
                return ', '.join(args)
            raise ValueError(f"invalid formatting mode {mode}")
        return formatter


foo = Foo()
print(foo.format("commas")('arg1', 'arg2'))
# arg1, arg2
```

Comment: This helped a ton thank you! I do find the task a bit weird as well which is why I was wondering.